# How to ping my website in Azure?

Tags: winforms, azure, ping

I wrote a Windows application to ping my website each 5 minutes to control whether it is UP or DOWN at the moment. it was working in our network and in our test server but our live environment is in Azure and it doesn't allow me to ping that web site.

What can I use instead of Ping to control my website in Azure? and how?

Comment: How does pinging control whether something is up or down?  Pinging may be able to tell you that the VM on which the website is running is up, but that's a "read-only" operation and doesn't control anything.

Comment: I would like to hear your suggestions instead of Ping, thats why I asked my question

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Do you want to monitor your website, or actually control whether it is up or down, or both?

Comment: I want to monitor my server whether it is up or down for some reason. I used HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse but after third time the program freezes for no reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse and remember to Dispose the objects you create. In particular the response stream of HttpWebResponse.

```
HttpWebResponse res = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
using (Stream respStream = res.GetResponseStream())
{
  respStream.ReadByte();
  respStream.Close();
}
```

Comment: Thx @Fabrizio , I closed my response and now it keeps on working ;)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you take it outside of your own infrastructure. Mainly because `ping`'ing something can give you very limited information anyway. What if the role is up and running but your website is actually crashing with an exception? What if you have multiple instances of your role, one of which is down, and your ping request doesn't say anything is wrong?

Use something like Pingdom:

http://www.pingdom.com

It'll allow you to do a few things, that are probably not possible (or not easy) to do with your own 'inhouse' solution. Such as transaction monitoring (similar to very basic UI tests, have a user log in and click around for instance), multiple ways of alerting (even Twitter alerts) and multiple different request locations (it may work in the UK, but does it work when accessing it from France?).

Services like this were created for this sole purpose. You need to define when you believe your website to "be up" or "be down". Is it when it responds to `ping`'s? Is it when your login page displays OK? Is it when your admin page displays OK?

Comment: Pingdom is also free for one site (The last time I checked). Pings from numerous servers across the world giving you the average response time in MS and gives you handy email notifications when the site is 'down' and 'up' again. They also provide a monthly report of your site.

Comment: It is worth noting that while your argument is right, in this case it is wrong. You can't ping servers within Azure from pingdom because ICMP traffic is blocked by azure.

Answer (score 1):

I used HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse instead of Ping, but after 3 times the program freezes for some reason. I put everything in a try...catch block but it does not throw any exception either, only freezes.

```
 try
 {
      var myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
      var response = (HttpWebResponse)myRequest.GetResponse(); //After third time it freezes here

      if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
      {
          labelResult.Text += TxtIPAddress.Text + " is Available " + " " + System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + " " + Environment.NewLine;
      }
      else
      {                    
          labelResult.Text += TxtIPAddress.Text + " is Unavailable " +  System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + " " + Environment.NewLine;
      }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {             
      labelResult.Text += TxtIPAddress.Text + " is Unavailable " + System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + " " + Environment.NewLine;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Another monitoring tool which is more complex is [PRTG](http://www.paessler.com/prtg)

It provides a number of monitors and is free for so many sensors you wish to monitor.

This way you can monitor not just a sites existence but whether a web service for a specific call returns, a SQL query. The possibilities are almost endless.